# Best practices to save "large" data from numerical computations

Tags: export, dumpsave

After solving PDEs with `NDSolve` and saving data with `DumpSave`, sometimes, Mathematica pops up a window saying "Abort or Continue waiting", especially if the computation has consumed lots of memories.

Specifically, in my computation, I used `NDSolve` to solve 2 equations for `f[x,t]` and `g[x,t]`, then saved with `DumpSave["~\result.mx","Global`"]`.
Usually, in this case, I need to click "Continue waiting" many many times to save the data, however, in more cases, it will abort in the end ...

Can anybody please share your experience with saving data of "large" computation (here, I use quotation marks since the data was actually not that large from my viewpoint, say ~1000M, but it may be large from Mathematica's point of view)? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can split the `t`-interval into smaller chunks? That is an advice you can get without being more specific about the code.